# MySQL - how to return a list of iD number from another table excluding a specific ID number

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a performance evaluation system. This is my example database:

```
Table: Person
ID     Name
--     ---
1      James
2      John
3      Jake

Table: Evaluation
-------  --  ------------
Eval_ID  ID  Evaluator_ID
0        1       2
```

I need a query where I can find a list of ID number from person that has not been evaluated by the evaluator_ID. So for example the ID number 1 would not be displayed from the result since it has been already evaluated by 2. So only the ID number 3 will be displayed because you cannot evaluate yourself.

Comment: `select .... where not in (select ...)`?

Comment: I suggest that you learn about **sql**.

Comment: what about 2? it's not evaluated by anyone and it can be evaluated by 1 or 3, can it?

Comment: @Tim3880 yes. You just can't evaluate yourself.

Comment: Then i think you need edit your questions to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Person
FROM Person p
WHERE p.ID NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.ID FROM Evaluation e WHERE p.ID = e.ID OR p.ID = e.Evaluator_ID)
```

Comment: Your query should be return also id 2.

Comment: id 1 and 2 both are evaluated. so 2 is not required.

Comment: Do you mean "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.ID FROM Evaluation e WHERE p.ID = e.ID)" ?

Comment: I think you need remove the "p.ID" before "NOT EXISTS".

Comment: @Tim3880 not when you are comparing more than 1 field

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name
FROM Person p
WHERE p.ID NOT in (SELECT e.ID FROM Evaluation e group by e.id )
 and   p.ID NOT in (SELECT f.Evaluator_ID FROM Evaluation f group by f.Evaluator_ID )
```